# C : warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c, strtok

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char * word;
    char line[255];
    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    while(fgets(line,255,fp)){
        word=strtok(line," ");
        while(word){
            printf("%s",word);
            word=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
    }
}
```

This the warning I get.

```
token.c:10:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   word=strtok(line," ");
       ^

token.c:13:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    word=strtok(NULL," ");
        ^
```

The `word` is declared as `char*`. Then why this warning arises?

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Oh.. Thats it :+1

Comment: Take your compiler's warning serious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Include `#include <string.h>` to get the prototype for `strtok()`.

Your compiler (like in pre-C99 C) assumed `strtok()` returns an `int` because of that. But not providing function declaration/prototype is not valid in modern C (since C99).

There used an old rule in C which allowed implicit function declarations. But *implicit int rule* has been removed from C language since C99.

See: [C function calls: Understanding the "implicit int" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220463/1275169)

Comment: Thanks @P.P. Solved.

Comment: Just trying to get some clarification, standard also _explicitly_ mentions the words "implicit function declaration", isn't it?

Comment: But I didn't claim to quote the standard. The rule that involves both implicit function dec and implicit type for params -- both assumed to be int is commonly called as implicit int rule. Both of them have been referred so and removed in C99.

Comment: OK sir, just to get my facts correct then, implicit int rule is not only for omitted type, it also includes the implicit function declaration, right?

Comment: Also, you mentioned _I said "implicit int rule" (as used in the C standards)_ but I can't seem to find a usage, can you please refer to the usage, please? Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 4):

`strtok()` is prototyped in `<string.h>`, you need to include it.

Otherwise, with the lack of forward declaration, your compiler *assumes* that any function used for which the signature is not known to it, returns an `int` and accepts any number of parameters. This *was* called [implicit declarration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) .

FWIW, implicit function declaration is now invalid as per the latest standard. Quoting `C11`, Foreward, "Major changes in the second edition included:"

> - remove implicit function declaration

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `string.h`

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks I got it